# Equivalence between two versions of Open Mapping Theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I have seen two versions of the open mapping theorem. I am trying to understand why they are equivalent.

From wikipedia:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $A : X \rightarrow Y$ is a surjective continuous linear operator, then $A$ is an open map.

From Royden (paraphrased):

> Let $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $T : X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous linear operator. $T(X)$ is closed as a subspace of $Y$ iff $T$ is an open map.

How are these equivalent?

EDIT:

I've included the releveant portion in Royden. Indeed, he discusses the image as having inherited the subspace topology from $Y$ -- I missed this before the discussion in the comments, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Presumably, you mean $A$ in your second statement, not $T$?

Comment: Wrong paraphrasing. There is no such theorem in Royden.

Comment: @uniquesolution The 4th edition has it.

Comment: There is also here http://mathonline.wikidot.com/equivalence-of-norms-on-banach-spaces

Comment: @FedericoFallucca - your argument in your answer contradicts the theorem in the link in your comment. Which is true?

Comment: @uniquesolution No because in that case it is clear that the map T is $T:X\to T(X)$ is open, infact there is no contraddiction if you consider the result of the link with respect this map.

Comment: @FedericoFallucca. If $T$ is open and $T(X)$ is closed, then $T(X)$ must equal $Y$. That we agree. On the other hand, The zero linear map $T:X\to Y$ obviously satisfies that $T(X)$ is closed in $Y$, but clearly $T$ is not open. Doesn't this contradict the theorem?

Comment: No because you must specify what map $T$ is open: is it open the map $ T:X\to Y$ or the map $T:X\to T(X)$?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca In that case, my friend, the theorem is not formulated precisely. We are given a continuous linear operator $T:X\to Y$. If we say that this operator is open, we mean that $TU$ is open in $Y$ for every $U$ open in $X$. There is no other definition. So if you say "$T(X)$ is closed iff $T$ is open", but you really want to say "$T(X)$ is closed iff $T$ is open as a map between $X$ and the range of $T$ in the relative topology", then you should say it. As it stands, the theorem is simply false, and I don't believe Royden would write such a thing.

Comment: Perfect, then it is clear that is not true the equivalenze of two statements, because I get an example in which T is continuos, linear and T(X) is closed but T is not open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that the second result implies the first result.

If it is true the first result, we consider a map $T:X\to Y$ such that $T(X)$ is closed. Each closed subspace of a Banach Space $Y$ is also a Banach Space so $T(X)$ is a Banach Space and $T:X \to T(X)$ is a surjective continuos linear operator between Banach Spaces; so, by first result, $T:X\to T(X)$ will be an open map. In any case, it is not true that $T: X\to Y$ will be an open map because in general $T(X)$ it is not open in $Y$, infact if it is open, then $T(X)$ will be a nonempty open and closed subspace of the connected space $Y$, so $T(X)=Y$. An example can be $T:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that

$T(x):=(x,0)$ . The map is continuos and Linear while the two spaces are Banach, so $T:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ is open while

$T:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is not open because $T(\mathbb{R})= \mathbb{R}\times \{0\}$ that it is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.